# Creating an invalid reference via reinterpret cast

Tags: c++, standards, language-lawyer, reinterpret-cast, strict-aliasing

I am trying to determine whether the following code invokes undefined behavior:

```
#include <iostream>

class A;

void f(A& f)
{
  char* x = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&f);
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    std::cout << x[i];
}

int main(int argc, char** argue)
{
  A* a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(new char[5])
  f(*a);
}
```

My understanding is that `reinterpret_cast`s to and from `char*` are compliant because the standard permits aliasing with `char` and `unsigned char` pointers (emphasis mine):

> If a program **attempts to access** the stored value of an object through an lvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> - the dynamic type of the object,
> - a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union),
> - a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of the dynamic type of the object,
> - **a `char` or `unsigned char` type.**

However, I am not sure whether `f(*a)` invokes undefined behavior by creating a `A&` reference to the invalid pointer. The deciding factor seems to be what "attempts to access" verbiage means in the context of the C++ standard.

My intuition is that this does *not* constitute an access, since an access would require `A` to be defined (it is declared, but not defined in this example). Unfortunately, I cannot find a concrete definition of "access" in the C++ standard:

**Does `f(*a)` invoke undefined behavior? What constitutes "access" in the C++ standard?**

I understand that, regardless of the answer, it is likely a bad idea to rely on this behavior in production code. I am asking this question primarily out of a desire to improve my understanding of the language.

**[Edit]** @SergeyA cited this section of the standard. I've included it here for easy reference (emphasis mine):

> **5.3.1/1 [expr.unary.op]**
>
> The unary `*` operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression points. If the type of the expression is “pointer to `T`,” the type of the result is “`T`.” [Note: indirection through a pointer to an incomplete type (other than cv void) is valid. **The lvalue thus obtained can be used in limited ways (to initialize a reference, for example); this lvalue must not be converted to a prvalue, see 4.1.** — end note ]

Tracing the reference to 4.1, we find:

> **4.1/1 [conv.lval]**
>
> A glvalue (3.10) of a non-function, non-array type `T` can be converted to a prvalue. If `T` is an incomplete type, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed. If T is a non-class type, the type of the prvalue is the cv-unqualified version of `T`. Otherwise, the type of the prvalue is `T`.
>
> **When an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to an expression `e`**, and either:
>
> - `e` is not potentially evaluated, or
> - the evaluation of `e` results in the evaluation of a member `ex` of the set of potential results of `e`, and `ex` names a variable `x` that is not odr-used by `ex` (3.2)
>
> the value contained in **the referenced object is not accessed**.

I think our answer lies in whether `*a` satisfies the second bullet point. I am having trouble parsing that condition, so I am not sure.

Comment: What is the alignment of `A`?

Answer (score 5):

`char* x = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&f);` is valid. Or, more specifically, access through `x` is allowed - the cast itself is always valid.

`A* a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(new char[5])` is not valid - or, to be precise, access through `a` will trigger undefined behaviour.

The reason for this is that while it's OK to access object through a `char*`, it's not OK to access array of chars through a random object. Standard allows first, but not the second.

Or, in layman terms, you can alias a `type*` through `char*`, but you can't alias `char*` through `type*`.

**EDIT**

I just noticed I didn't answer direct question ("*What constitutes "access" in the C++ standard*"). Apparently, Standard does not define *access* (at least, I was not able to find the formal definition), but dereferencing the pointer is commonly understood to qualify for access.

Comment: I agree that "access through `a` will trigger undefined behavior," but (like you mention), `A* a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(new char[5])` may not constitute an access. Again, the answer comes down to what constitutes an "access". Is the *pointer deference* or the *conversion to an lvalue* (I may be getting the type wrong) the "access"?

Comment: `A* a = ...` is not an access. But dereferencing a pointer is an access.

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but *why not*? It is not clear to me why `A& b = *a` is inherently any more of an access than `A* b = a` is. Neither of those statements require `A` to be defined; only declared. Is there anything in the standard that hints at this interpretation?

Comment: Yes, and I said it several times - **dereferencing a pointer**. A specific standard term is *indirection*, and as specified in 5.3.1 / 1, indirection to incomplete type is allowed to initialize a reference. However, it is still understood to be access.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to 5.3.1 / 1 - that is definitely relevant. However, I am specifically looking for a statement in the standard that says that dereferencing a pointer (indirection) constitutes "access". I followed the reference to 4.1 / 1 that defines when lvalue to prvalue conversion constitutes access. I am not positive, but I think `A& b = *a`  is not an access because the result is not odr-used.

Comment: @MichaelKoval, well, to the best of my knowldge, standard doesn't have formal definition for access. However, this seems to be the actual essence of your question. In this case, I suggest you ask another straightforward question, free from any type aliasing or anything - what does constitue an *access*. Provide this example (with reference to the same type, though). You are likely to get more interesting answers than here.

Comment: Fair enough. I will post another question specifically about the definition of "access" in the C++ standard.